# How to use Or inside the .find method?

Tags: python, string

So, I am running a code where I want to find either 'a' or 'b'

This returns -1:

```
string = 'b'
i = string.find('a' or 'b')
print(i)
```

This also returns -1:

```
string = 'b'
i = string.find('a') or string.find('b')
print(i)
```

What's the correct way of writing it?

Comment: So what is the *expected outcome*? `-1` or the position of `'a'` or `'b'`? Or just that *one of those substrings* is present (so `True` or `False`)?

Comment: Actually, I need the index of every a and b that presents itself on the code. My initial code was more complex than the one I present here, but since this was the problem I figured it would be fine to simplify it

Comment: There are much more efficient ways of doing *that*. `[i for i, letter in enumerate(string) if letter in {'a', 'b'}]` gives you a list of positions (it may be an empty list).

Comment: This is one of the reasons you should always include an [mcve] and a *clear problem statement* in your question.

Comment: Yeah, it was a mistake from my part, too much emphasis on the minimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.find()` returns `-1` if a string is not found, so you would have to *explicitly test for that*:

```
string.find('a') > -1 or string.find('b') > -1
```

However, this will only tell you if the string is *present*, not the index. You may as well just use `in`:

```
'a' in string or 'b' in string
```

If you needed the find the *position*, then you are better off storing the first result in a variable first:

```
a_pos = string.find('a')
pos = a_pos if a_pos > -1 else string.find('b')
```

Now `pos` is either `-1` (neither substring found), or the position of the substring that was found (so `'a'` if present, otherwise `'b'`). Do note, that you then know a position, but not which substring you found. That's probably not that useful *either*.

Comment: This doesn't give you the position of the substrings.

Comment: @Daniel: no, but finding an index for `'a'`, or `'b'` if `'a'` is not present, is not that helpful, really. If `pos` is not `-1`, which one of the two did we find?

Comment: @Daniel: besides, it is *far from clear* that the OP even wants a position.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in two steps:

```
string = 'b'
i = string.find('a')
if i < 0:
    i = string.find('b')
print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

In such case a regular expression *could* be a solution, although for the simple case you provide it would not be the fastest:

```
import re
m = re.search(r'a|b', string)
print(m and m.start())
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code will return True if either a or b are in your string

```
any(letter in string for letter in ('a','b'))
```

Also is easily extensible if you want to add more than just a or b